# How to get specific marker latitude and longitude among multiple marker in mapbox?

Tags: latitude-longitude, marker, mapbox-gl-js

In my map lot of markers but i want to specific marker latitude and longitude when i clicked it.

when i click a single marker for latitude and longitude i got all markers latitude and longitude.

```
navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(position => {

  var lat = position.coords.latitude;
  var lng = position.coords.longitude;

  var marker = new mapboxgl.Marker()
    .setLngLat([lng, lat])
    .addTo(this.map);`enter code here`

 function clickAndGetLatLngOfMarker()
  {
    var lngLat = marker.getLngLat();
    console.log(lngLat.lng);
    console.log(lngLat.lat);

  }

  this.map.on('click', clickAndGetLatLngOfMarker)

});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

A marker is an HTML element that exists in the DOM, not in the map. You should attach a click handler to it, using jQuery or similar, not using `map.on("click")`,

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I discovered the answer. simply i use marker array and it's solve my problem.